# pause specific if statement execution

Tags: php, if-statement, web, delay, statements

How to make specific `if-statement` delayed execution?

I need to show the first message, then next one will bring after x seconds. PHP with `sleep()` / `usleep()` is not working, it is just pausing whole script.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $number = $_POST['number '];

    if(empty($number ))
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='width: 27%;'>Ievadiet likmi!</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_numeric($number )) {

            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning' style='width: 27%;'>Rezultāts: <b>".$number ."</b>. Gaidiet rezultātu!</div>";
```

//Need to delay below

```
            if($number < 0.00)
            {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='width: 27%;'>Nekorekti ievadīts!</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success' style='width: 27%;'>Rezultāts!</div>";    
            }
```

//Need to delay above

```
        } else {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='width: 27%;'>Nekorekti ievadīts. Jāsatur cipariem!</div>";
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: if you think you can achieve this using php, you probably need a good book about Server Side Development / PHP

Comment: UX should be handled in the client (browser). Output the data as json and display it how ever you want using JS.

Comment: This is almost impossible to do with a pure server-side solution. Every tech stack your output goes through (PHP, web server, proxy, browser...) is specifically designed to prevent this. You can spend many hours trying to flush partial output and you'll always find a scenario where it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case someone stumbles on it: you cannot do this. What you want to do is only possible through client-side scripting (after the server-side scripting of course).

So you output a piece of html and javascript (through php) and let the javascript do the delaying parts. Time to learn Javascript!